# GitLab CI deployment without Docker for NodeJS application?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

Is it possible to implement GitLab CI workflow without using any Docker image?
All the examples I see for GitLab runner are based on docker only. Even for production deployment.

How can I implement GitLab CI and deployment process on my existing linux machines? On the production sever i want to deploy code run npm install if package.json modified and restart node instance

I want to use multiple runners and having docker image for each of it is resource consuming.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible. You can use shell executor in gitlab-ci-multi-runner. Here is example how to register runner:

```
sudo gitlab-ci-multi-runner register -n \
  --url https://gitlab.com/ci \
  --registration-token REGISTRATION_TOKEN \
  --executor shell \
  --description "My Runner"
```

Then all your scripts specified in **.gitlab-ci.yml** file will be executed in the shell on behalf of gitlab-runner user. [Here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/executors/shell.md) is detailed description of shell executor. And [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/executors/README.md) is comparision of different executors in gitlab-ci-multi-runner.